# Struggling with an identity which uses fourier expansions.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I need to show :

$$f(\theta)=\cos(n\theta)\int_{0}^{2\pi}w(\theta')\cos(n\theta')d\theta' =\int_{0}^{2\pi}w(\theta-\theta')\cos(n\theta')d\theta'$$

The author says, Fourier expanding the integrand of the right hand side leads to the result. I also know $w$ is $2\pi$ periodic and symmetric. I have been stuck on this for a long while now. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think I've made a typo.  It makes sense it's outside as both sides have to depend on $\theta$

Comment: I'm slightly confused by what you mean. On the lhs we are integrating with respect to $\theta$, on the rhs, with respect to $\theta'$. Sorry if I'm being abit slow here.

Comment: "The author says" - which author and which book?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I will change the LHS to be with respect to $\theta'$. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Is $w$ periodic?

Comment: ah yes. I completely forgot to mention $w$ is $2\pi$ periodic. I will ammend that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the RHS, use the substitution $x = \theta - \theta'$ to obtain
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}w(\theta - \theta')\cos(n \theta')\ d\theta'
= \int_{\theta - 2\pi}^{\theta} w(x)\cos(n(x - \theta))\ dx$$
Since the integrand is $2\pi$-periodic, we can integrate over any interval of length $2\pi$ without changing the result, so the above is the same as
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}w(x)\cos(n(x - \theta))\ dx$$
Applying the trig identity $\cos(a-b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) + \sin(a)\sin(b)$ gives us
$$\cos(n\theta)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} w(x)\cos(nx)\ dx +
\sin(n\theta)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} w(x)\sin(nx)\ dx$$
As $w$ is even and $\sin$ is odd, the integrand in the second integral is odd, so the second integral is zero. This leaves us with
$$\cos(n\theta)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} w(x)\cos(nx)\ dx$$
which is the same as
$$\cos(n\theta)\int_{0}^{2\pi} w(x)\cos(nx)\ dx$$
since as above, we can integrate over any interval of length $2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Performing the change of variables $\theta'\mapsto \theta-\theta'$ and using periodicity of the integrand to adjust the integration region ($w$ can be extended from a function over $[0,2\pi)$ to be a periodic function over all the real axis), we get
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} w(\theta-\theta')\cos(n\theta') d\theta' 
=\int_{\theta-2\pi}^{\theta}w(\theta')\cos(n\theta-n\theta') d\theta'  
=\int_{0}^{2\pi}w(\theta')\cos(n\theta-n\theta') d\theta'.
$$
Now, let us expand the last expression using the formula $\cos(n\theta-n\theta')=\cos(n\theta)\cos(n\theta')+\sin(n\theta)\sin(n\theta')$.
By assumption, $w(\theta')$ is symmetric, while $\sin(n\theta)$ is antisymmetric on the interval $[0,2\pi)$, hence
$$
\sin(n\theta)\int_0^{2\pi}w(\theta')\sin(n\theta')d\theta'=0.
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} w(\theta-\theta')\cos(n\theta') d\theta' = \cos(n\theta) \int_0^{2\pi}w(\theta')\cos(n\theta')d\theta'.
$$
Alternatively we can follow the hint given in the text and expand $w$ in its Fourier series (since it is symmetric, only the cosine series is needed)
$$
w(\theta-\theta')=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \cos(m(\theta-\theta'))\int_0^{2\pi} w(\tau)\cos(m\tau)d\tau.
$$
Substituting into
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}w(\theta-\theta')\cos(n\theta')d\theta'
$$
and using
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(n\theta')\cos(m(\theta-\theta'))d\theta'
=\cos(m\theta)\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(n\theta') \cos(m\theta')d\theta' = \pi \cos(n\theta) \delta_{nm}
$$
where $\delta_{nm}$ is the Kronecker symbol, again yields
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}w(\theta-\theta')\cos(n\theta')d\theta'=\cos(n\theta')\int_0^{2\pi}w(\tau)\cos(n\tau)d\tau
$$